# How life cycle events get handled by Handler of Main Thread?

Tags: android, event-handling, handler, android-lifecycle

I got to know that `activity` `lifecycles` are basically the events that get fired by the Android system and handled by the provided callback methods. But how?

As if they are events they should be in Massage Queue, they should be handled by a handler of `Main/UI` thread but that is not happening. The `callback` methods like `onCreate()` are being called but for that, there is no event is get registered or get a place in massage queue or get handled by `handleMassage()` of Handler of the main thread.

```
(no handleMassage() is called before any life cycle methods)
```

And also for `onClick()` events, no event gets a place in massage queue or handled by the handler of UI thread as no `handleMassage()` is getting called before calling the `onClick()` method.

Please let me know how these events are being handled if they are events and if I am wrong please correct me?

Comment: Basically Android handle lifecycle of Activity by different process you can research and read source class ActivityManagerService.

Comment: About View I agree with you some method relate draw happen on Message Queue of Main Thread. UI thread already has Message Queue but there are many handlers can associate with one Queue. It means you can not check it dispatch to handle message of your Handler

Comment: You can read source of Handler when you want to put message to Handler you should obtainMessage of your handler. It have to do that to make target Handler for this message you want to put it to Queue

Comment: `Basically Android handle lifecycle of Activity by different process` Is it the UI thread, Công Hải?